# How to run Migrations at AppStart

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fluent-migrator

I am using FluentMigrator.dll for DB settings and I want it can create or update its database when program ran any server.

So I visited this page for this problem

[Is it possible to use fluent migrator in application_start?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7574417/4699738)

And get these codes to my project;

```
public static void MigrateToLatest(string connectionString)
    {

        var announcer = new TextWriterAnnouncer(s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s));
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

        CreateDB(connectionString);

        var migrationContext = new RunnerContext(announcer)
        {
            Namespace = "Mueasyco.MVCWebUI.Migrations.DefaultDB"
        };

        var options = new MigrationOptions { PreviewOnly = false, Timeout = 60 };
        var factory =
            new FluentMigrator.Runner.Processors.SqlServer.SqlServer2012ProcessorFactory();

        using (var processor = factory.Create(connectionString, announcer, options))
        {
            var runner = new MigrationRunner(assembly, migrationContext, processor);
            runner.MigrateUp();
        }
    }
```

You will see at there CreateDB() method, it provides a DB for my project.

So, MigrateUp() does not give any errors but it does not work

Thanks for your answers